# Symfony return video in controller

Tags: php, symfony, video-streaming

I want to do some filters about user and permision to video and I do a route:

```
app_filter_f:
    path: /products/{idProduct}/movies/{name}.mp4
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:App:filterRequest }
```

and a controler with a action similar with https://creativcoders.wordpress.com/2014/05/12/symfony2-how-to-send-video-response-to-twig-view/ with filesystem https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($fs->read('14/movies/session1_ch1.mp4'),200,[
                'Content-Type' => 'video/mp4',
                'Connection' => 'close',
                'Content-Length' => $fs->size('14/movies/session1_ch1.mp4')
            ]);
```

the problem is my video is load in page, but i cant go to a next minute, only can go back, but ahead not.

on frontend I used html5:

```
<video id="course-video" width="100%" controls>
    <source src="{{ course.modules.first.movies.isEmpty() ? '' :course.modules.first.movies.first().downloadPath }}" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

I was try to find any solution with that but I don't found, is posible to simulate a returned video with symfony, and work to change minute ahead and back ?

Comment: I would return a [BinaryFileResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html) instead.

Comment: thank you, i was returned a BinaryFileResponse with autoEtag and now work, thank you very mach !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse

$response = new BinaryFileResponse($webPath);
$response->setAutoEtag(true);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
return $response;
```